# How to return an object from a dictionary value?

Tags: python

I have several classes, each holding its own Neural Network architecture.

Based on a user-entered flag, `rx_flag`, I am trying to retrieve a specific architecture in the driver file.

I have two problems:

1. *I am unable to create a dictionary in the usual way. The following format is not working:*

   ```py
   def build_model(rx_flag):
       switcher = {
           'xss': XSS().get_model(),
           'rss': RSS().get_model()
       }
       return switcher.get(rx_flag)
   ```
2. *After some research, I am finally able to at least construct a dictionary where the models in those classes are stored as values, but when I return them to the `main()` method, I get the `NoneType`.*

Here is my class. The other classes have a similar template. I have commented out the implementation of `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` because storing in the dictionary seems to be working fine without it too.

```py
from model import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

class XSS(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_layers = 2
        self.input_dim = 3
        self.output_dim = 1
        self.architecture = [64, 32]
        self.model = Sequential()

    def get_model( self , arch=[64, 32]):
        # add input layer
        self.model.add(Dense(arch[0], activation='relu', input_shape=(self.input_dim, )))

        # add intermediate layers
        for i in range(1, self.num_layers):
            self.model.add(Dense(arch[i], activation='relu'))

        # add output layer
        self.model.add(Dense(self.output_dim, activation='linear'))
        return self.model

    def get_name( self ):
        return 'xss'

    def get_value( self ):
        return self.__value()

    def __value( self ):
        return (self.model, self.num_layers, self.input_dim, self.output_dim, self.architecture)

    # def __hash__(self):
    #     return (self.hash(self.__value()))
    #
    # def __eq__(self, other):
    #     if isinstance(other, XSS):
    #         return self.__value() == other.__value()
    #     return NotImplemented
```

This is the driver code:

```py
import sys

from model import Model
from xss import XSS

def build_model(rx_flag):
    switcher = {}
    obX = XSS()
    switcher[obX.get_name()] = obX.get_model()
    obR = RSS()
    switcher[obR.get_name()] = obR.get_model()
    print(switcher)
    return switcher.get(rx_flag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rx_flag = sys.argv[0]
    # create a model instance based on flag
    model = build_model(rx_flag)
    model.summary()
```

This is the error that I get on attempting `model.summary()`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/path/driver.py", line 19, in <module>
    model.summary()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

How can I build the dictionary in a more Pythonic way, and have it return the actual model?

Comment: Try printing `rx_flag`... It's not what you think it is

Comment: That was a typographical error. I am returning it. Let me edit that. I still get the error when I return.

Comment: try to use `switcher[rx_flag]` instead of `switcher.get(rx_flag)`

Comment: I tried printing `rx_flag`. Turns out that `sys.argv[0]` is the file name after all. I am running it in PyCharm and entered the user flag in the run configuration parameters but it couldn't read it for some reason. When I run it from the terminal, it works. Thanks! Still get the error on PyCharm though. I'll just stick to the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) suggested that rx_flag is not what I think it is. They are right.

The code works fine even on PyCharm when I initialize `rx_flag` as below:

```py
rx_flag = sys.argv[1]
```

I was under the impression that it is the first parameter when I enter it in the run configuration on PyCharm.